# Python re.findall() not working as expected - Finding string between anchors

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have text I need to parse which has this pattern:

```
Lorem ipsum, baby shark, do do doo

    Host: MyHostName

Blah, Blah
```

I am trying to isolate the line `Host: MyHostName`

In regex101 this regex works well `(?<=Host:).*?(?=$)` but for some reason Python's `re.findall()` keeps returning an empty list. I have tweaked it in several ways but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Is there something I am overlooking here???

(Note: I am using Python 3.6)

**EDIT**   My code in context

```
import re
pattern = r'(?<=Host:)(.*)(?=$)' 
data = """ 
        Lorem Ipsum...
          Host: MyHostName
        """

x = re.findall(pattern, data)
```

Comment: Please show the whole code you used.

Comment: add multiline as in my answer

Comment: You don't need `(?=$)`, just use `$`, it doesn't match anything. And why use the non-greedy `.*?`, especially since you seem to want to the end of the line ?

Comment: @LogicalKip  when I convert to just `$` is returns empty again.

Comment: You do not need `$` in the first place. Use `pattern = r'Host:\s*(.+)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=Host:).*?(?=$)"

test_str = ("Lorem ipsum, baby shark, do do doo\n\n"
    "    Host: MyHostName\n\n"
    "Blah, Blah")

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

print(matches)
```

Comment: - This seems to work. I have several other regexs that are working fine without MULTILINE - Why do I need it here? ?

Comment: in case of multilines the pattern character '$' matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line

Comment: I will, I am just trying to understand what is happening here first

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple and just use the following regex pattern:

```
\bHost: \S+
```

Script:

```
text = """Lorem ipsum, baby shark, do do doo

    Host: MyHostName

Blah, Blah"""

matches = re.findall(r'\bHost: \S+', text)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['Host: MyHostName']
```

Comment: - This works, but I wanted to point out that it returns `[Host: MyHostName]` not `['MyHostName`]